# Git Daemon on linux?

Tags: linux, git

Trying to set up a simple git-daemon on a linux server, and talk to it from a windows box.

On linux server:

1. Make a folder **/home/foo/bar**
2. **CD** to **/home/foo/bar**
3. do a **git --bare init** here
4. Do a **touch git-daemon-export-ok**
5. **CD** to **/home/foo**
6. Run the command **git-daemon --verbose --reuseaddr --base-path=/home/foo --enable=receive-pack**

On Windows Client w tortoise Git

1. Do **git.exe clone --progress -v  "git://servername/bar" "C:\source\myFolderName"** (works)
2. Create file a.txt, add it to git, and commit (works)
3. Do a **git.exe pull  "origin" master** and then get **fatal: Couldn't find remote ref master** (makes sense, master isn't there yet)
4. Do a **git.exe push    "origin" master:master** and tortoise hangs forever without do anything

I realize why I can't pull from master yet on the remote branch.. but why can't I push my first commit into the remote repo?  #4 really should work. Tried it both with tortoise and the mysysgit command line, both cases I hang forever. What am I missing?  Server has no useful log

Comment: Does pushing to empty repository works if it is done via SSH?  Does pushing via git-daemon works if there is at least one commit in destination repository?

Comment: SSH works fine. I can push and pull all day long. But trying to access the same thing with git-daemon, all I get is the forever-hang.

Comment: As an alternative I'm currently using: http://www.mobiphil.com/2010/03/git-on-shared-hosting-with-git-http-backend/ - Also allows push and pull but (AFAIK) requires a per repository configuration setting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this is probably a bug in msysgit http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/issues/detail?id=457

As of right now there is a workaround (not in the main branch I think) but no true fix.

Answer (score 2):

I tend to access repositories read/write from my server using:

`git remote add git@server.com:/repository`

Which is git over ssh, not via git daemon. You could use this configuration provided `user@server` has access to the repository.

Some other things you can do with this:

- Create a user called git with a shell `/usr/bin/git-shell`. The user will only be able to perform git operations if you do this - ssh won't work.
- Create a `/home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys` file which contains ssh keys that can connect. Any keys added here will let you commit, so you can add several different users' keys.

This setup lets you control who can commit whilst letting anyone clone via the efficient git:// protocol.

However, if you do want to receive packs, I think the correct command is:

```
git-daemon --verbose --reuseaddr --export-all --base-path=/home/foo --enable=receive-pack
```

As per [this stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/792611/receive-pack-service-not-enabled-for-git).

Comment: I don't have root on this server, and I can't make users. Need to get git-daemon to work, not use ssh and proper users.

Only difference from this to my git command, is the --export-all.. but since I am already doing touch git-daemon-export-ok, it doesn't help :*(